# I need help with app development

Tags: adobe-photoshop, windows, applications

I am building my very first app. I have the concept and I have built the frames  in photoshop CC. I want to turn it into a live app - I am overwhelmed with the different programmes & software available...free/paid xcode codly etc etc

I am running windows 7 64bit system. I would like to able to get an understanding as to what i need to do now to make my concept into a fully working app.

I know people pay alot of money for app development so i am simply after some friendly advice/tips from an experienced app developer/programmer. The approach - programmes etc

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with Graphic Design. There might be a better exchange for you but no idea which. There's StackExchanges for game development, iOS, Android, Programming, and of course StackOverflow. Any one of these are probably better than here for your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are ready to spend time developping your app on iOs and Android I suggest you to use Android studio and learning java/android and XCode for the iOS development using Objective C or Swift(idk where Swift is atm)

If not, you can develop your app in a "web" way with html/css/[AngularJs](https://angularjs.org/) and [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/) which will give you only one source code and two apps (idk about Windows Phone)

**Edit**

Considering the fact that you have a mac, all the solutions I give here are completely free :)

Have a good day :)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, wise words, thanks for the advice! New to all this but if theres 14yokids making millions of these apps I'm sure i can having been a graphic designer for 10years (LOL)

Pea's

Comment: It's all about the concept and how you sell it ;) Good luck and have fun coding :)

Comment: Copy that, cheers!